# In android how to create a shared preferences when the application is installed?

Tags: android

Hi I'am new to android.
I want to create a shared preferences when the app is first installed and the insert some data.
The shared preference has to be used from all activities in the app.
I tried creating the shared preference in the onCreate() function of the first activity and inserted values into it.And edited the data from another activity.
But when I restart the app the shared preference changes to the data give in the 
onCreate().
Can somebody help me?

Comment: its because, you are inserting some data in onCreate of first activity. When app is restarted, First activity is launched and onCreate code is executed which is over-writing on the data written by Second activity

Comment: Post your code!

Comment: public class StartActivity extends Activity {  
@Override  
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
setContentView(R.layout.activity_start);  
SharedPreferences   myprefs=getSharedPreferences("mypref",MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor=myprefs.edit();  
editor.putString("name,"sha");  
editor.commit();  
}  
}

Answer (score 0):

The way if you want to insert data once:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("myPref", MODE_PRIVATE);
    boolean shouldInsertData = preferences.getBoolean("shouldInsertData", true);

    if(shouldInsertData){

        //insert your data into the preferences

        preferences.edit().putBoolean("shouldInsertData", false).apply();

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Share Preference is best way to store short information. but if you will create share preference from an active, it may create problem to access it from other activity.
**You should create a global common share preference from application** so you can access it through out the android project, any where in any activity. 
I get [reference from here](https://www.blueappsoftware.com/course/ecommerce-android-app-development/lessons/share-preference-create-splash-screen/) -
It is 4 step process.

**Step 1**- create a java class file name as "myapp" and extend it by application.

---

```
public class MyApp extends Application {
private static Context context;
private String TAG ="myApp";
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    context = getApplicationContext();
   // Log.e(TAG, "  myapp stater");
}

public static Context getContext(){
    return context;
}}
```

**Step 2** - in android manifest file inside application tab add android:name=".myapp"

**Step 3** - Create java class name as "SharePreferenceUtils" (note don't use name SharePreference.)

---

public class SharePreferenceUtils {

```
private static String PREFERENCE_NAME = "shopeasy-ecommerce";
private static SharePreferenceUtils sharePreferenceUtils;
private SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;

private SharePreferenceUtils(Context context){
    PREFERENCE_NAME = PREFERENCE_NAME + context.getPackageName();
    this.sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFERENCE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
}

public static SharePreferenceUtils getInstance(){
    if (sharePreferenceUtils == null){
         sharePreferenceUtils = new SharePreferenceUtils(SplashActivity.getContext());
    }
    return sharePreferenceUtils;
}

// login response user_id 1234
public void saveString(String key,  String Val ){
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putString(key, Val);
    editor.commit();
}

public String getString(String key, String defVal){
    return sharedPreferences.getString(key, defVal);
}


public String getString(String key){
    return sharedPreferences.getString(key, "");
}

public void saveInt(String key,  int Val ){
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putInt(key, Val);
    editor.commit();
}

public int getInteger(String key){ return sharedPreferences.getInt(key, 0 ); }

/**
 * Clear all values from this preference
 */
public void clear() {
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.clear();
    editor.commit();
}

/**
 * Clear value of given key from this preference
 *
 * @param key name of the key whose value to be removed
 */
public void clearString(String key) {
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.remove(key);
    editor.commit();
}}
```

**Step 4** Call sharePreferenceUtil from activity
**SharePreferenceUtils.getInstance().saveString("Username", "username value here");**

Now you can access sharepreference from any activity. Just call instance of sharepreference java class.